# how to save output file.txt after hashing sha256 in python

Tags: python, sha256

I am trying to hash sha256 using python.
I got the result like this but I don't know how to save the hash result to file.txt. Please help me to edit the command.

```
import hashlib
with open('x.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        print(hashlib.sha256(line.encode()).hexdigest())
```

> 9869f9826306f436e1a8581b7ce467d38bab6e280839fd88fd51d45de39b6409
> b51d80a47274161a0eeb44cfa1586ee9c4bc3d33740895a4d688f9090e24d8c2
> f0f2ea3096f72e0d6916f9febd912a17fd9c91e83dd9e558967e21329dfbe393
> 4799d169d99c206ae68fe96c67736d88b6976c1a47ce2383ced8de9edf41ade9
> 2a68d417af41750b17a1b65b2002c5875b2b40232d54f7566e1fc51f5395b9f9
> 826c4d573dc5766eb44461f76ce0ca08487e9d5894583214b7c52bdf032039c4

results like this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBj1p.png

Comment: Why did you tag the questions with the tags [m] and [b-lang], but not [python]?

Comment: I'm a newbie, and I've only been into programming for a few days

Comment: I am trying to hash sha256 using python. I got the result like this but I don't know how to save the hash result to file.txt. Please help me...thanks you

Comment: can you help me https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBj1p.png

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image. Go back and edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the file with the `w` flag and write to it.

See the documentation on [`Reading and Writing Files`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

```py
import hashlib
with open('x.txt') as f_in, open('file.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.strip()
        f_out.write(hashlib.sha256(line.encode()).hexdigest())
```

**PS.** you're not hashing the file properly, you should not use `line.strip()` as it means you hash the line without leading/trailing spaces/tabs/newlines.

Comment: I don't know what else to say, thank you so much
Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You have one file ('x.txt') opened to read line by line, so you'll need to open another file to write your output.

You could write line by line:

```
import hashlib

with open("x.txt") as f:
    with open("file.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            hash = hashlib.sha256(line.encode()).hexdigest()
            outfile.write(hash + "\n")
```

Or you could define a list, append every line, and write once:

```
import hashlib

hashes = []

with open("x.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        hash = hashlib.sha256(line.encode()).hexdigest()
        hashes.append(hash + "\n")

with open("file.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(hashes)
```

Note that you would need to append "\n" to jump to a new line.

Comment: I don't know what else to say, thank you so much
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
import hashlib
with open('x.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        txt_to_write = hashlib.sha256(line.encode()).hexdigest())
with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(txt_to_write)
```

You have to create a file and write in it.
You put the result of your hash in a variable and you write it.
Here the file will be created in your current repository.

Comment: I don't know what else to say, thank you so much
Have a nice day